# How to force a Xen VM to run a program

Tags: virtual-machines, xen

I need to force Xen virtual machine to run a program. Thus, I'm looking for a way to make a script, which could be executed on the host machine and make VM to run the program

Also, there's a question - is it possible to automate configuring VMs to have them already got the executable I need (before starting the VM actually or, maybe, make it copy the executable just after start)?

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: What type of linux are you running? For RHEL/Centos you can use kickstart to automate configuration. To run commands, have a look at salt saltstack.org

Comment: I think he's looking for more of a VPS type solution. Where the host can execute commands on the host through a web console.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at JeOS (JustEnoughOperatingSystem).
It's available based on SuSE and Oracle VM and specially intended for single-application virtual machines.

That's not saying it's still a lot more complex than you seem to be assuming :)